# Re-fecthing and Rendering Collection After Adding/Changing Model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have an "index" view and an accompanying "pagination" view. On initialization, the index view fetches the relevant collection. The initially fetched collection is limited to 100 models and contains the count of all values in the collection. The count is passed to the pagination view and it accordingly produces page numbers. After the 10th page (10 records/page) The next 100 models are fetched, and so on the pattern continues.

Keeping the aforementioned in mind, when I add one or more models to the collection the model count will need to be re-fetched from the server (so the pages can be re-calculated), even though I do:

`@collection.add [new_model]`

However, in the event of changing a value in a model, I simply want the collection to be re-rendered.

With the following initialization code, I'm able to have the collection re-rendered after a change. But in the event of a "add" nothing happens. How can I construct the view to re-fetch from the server the new collection and count?

Note: I'm using `fetch(add: true)`

```
initialize: ->
    @collection = new MyApp.MyCollection()
    @collection.on('add', @render, @)
    @collection.on('change', @render, @)
    @collection.fetch(add: true)
```

Comment: I'm confuse, I can't understand the full meaning of the first sentence :/

Comment: @fguillen Sorry, the lack of clarity in the original post. Hopefully the revisions will make the question clearer.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify the events logic:

- **reset**: will be triggered after a fetch from the server. A fetch drops all content of the collection and just inserts everything in the collection that comes from the server
- **add**: will be triggered after a model has been added to the collection. **ATTENTION**: add will not be triggered by a fetch, unless you use the add:True option.
- **change**: will be triggered after the content/field of a model has changed. **ATTENTION**: change will not be triggered by fetch nor by adding a model.

So the events do hardly overlap but all serve a specific use case. You have that in mind when binding the events to methods, especially the render method.